# svnsync: E020014: Failed to find label 'NULL' for URL '/svn/MyRepo/!svn/rev/37'

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, svnsync

We have mirror database in our network and master database in another network. We are getting the error "svnsync: E020014: Failed to find label 'NULL' for URL '/svn/MyRepo/!svn/rev/37'" in between during sync the mirror via https protocol(Internet).

If I'm running the command again, it's start syncing the revisions. Again we are getting the same error after some time.
Can anyone help to resolve this error ?

Comment: What server and svnsync version do you have?

Comment: We are using VisualSVN Server 2.5.9 version and svnsync 1.7.5 version.

Comment: VisualSVN Server 2.5.x is not supported starting from September 29, 2015. Upgrade to the latest VisualSVN Server 3.9.x and consider using the [VDFS replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) instead of `svnsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You use a very old and unsupported version of VisualSVN Server. You need to upgrade to the latest version and see whether it helps. Contact support@visualsvn.com if the upgrade does not help resolve the issue.

Read the article [KB138: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.9](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00138/) before beginning the upgrade.